# Is the Cambridge Certificate of English accepted in US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, language-exams

According to CEF, CAE and CPE are the highest level possible. If I apply to some top US university/college, will they accept a certificate from Cambridge instead of TOEFL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should read the minimum requirements of the program at the university to which you are applying. Some universities only accept TOEFL, some other only accept IELTS, some universities accept both of these, and some universities accept those certificates like FCE, CAE or CPE as well as TOEFL or IELTS. (Some other universities also accept the English tests which are designed by themselves.)

I have seen some tables in which the minimum scores of each test is mentioned. For instance a university may accept a 7.0 of IELTS, 100 iBT (internet based TOEFL) and an A of FCE.

So the only advice I can give you is to check the minimum English language requirements of the university *and* the program you are applying.

Comment: Seconded. And even if the university does not state it at the web page, it does not hurt to ask. If you have a very good result at your test, they may make an exception if it is clear that your request is about saving the money for another test rather than circumventing the requirement that you speak and write English well.